# How to replace JSON_EXTRACT for ->> in WHILE or REPEAT

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

how to replace 0 with a counter (i) ->  _payments->>'$[0].name'

```
while i < JSON_LENGTH(_payments) do                             
    select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(_payments,CONCAT('$[',i,'].name')));
    select i+1 into i;
end while;


while i < JSON_LENGTH(_payments) do
    select _payments->>'$[0].name';
    select i+1 into i;
end while;
```

I am trying to reduce the code of the json_extract for ->> in json_array.
try the following:

```
while i < JSON_LENGTH(_payments) do
    select _payments->>concat("'$[",i,"].name'");
    select i+1 into i;
end while;

and

while i < JSON_LENGTH(_payments) do
    select _payments->>concat('$[',i,'].name');
    select i+1 into i;
end while;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `[plsql]`? Are you asking for a MySQL (or PHP?) specific solution?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL. The 2 are not really that similiar? I removed both tags, please add back only the one that is actually relevant to your situation

Comment: I've also removed the PHP tag, because it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Oooh, 5.7? Condolences.

Comment: i doubt that you can do it stay with your code as it was